# Return Observable within Async Function

Tags: angular, http, asynchronous, observable

I'm having trouble with the data I get from the server. I need to check if a username is available and then execute an http.get which is no problem, thing is I need to return the content of the http.get as an observable to create an object later.

```
registerUser(user: RegisterComponent): Observable<any> {

  let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  let exists = this.http.get(this.url + "verifyCuentaUsuarioApp.php?cuenta=" + user.cuentaUser + "&id=" + user.passUser);

  exists.subscribe(response => {
    if (response != null) {
      //console.log("this is the message "+response.mensaje);
      if (response.data[0].estatus == "0") {
        console.log("disponible");
        //I need the content of this request to be returned 
        this.http.get(this.url + 'registroClienteApp.php?' + params, { headers: headers });
      } else
        console.log("no disponible");
    }
  });

  return this.http.get(this.url + 'registroClienteApp.php?' + params, { headers: headers });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to return an Observable? Start not with not subscribing but piping the Observable and use any of the flattening rxjs operators, for example:

```
this.http.get(// first request here).pipe(
    mergeMap((dataFromFirstRequest) => {
        if (dataFromFirstRequest suits requirement for second request) {
            return this.http.get(// second http request)
        } else {
            return of(false);   // return a falsy data indicating second request wasn't needed
        }
    })
)
```

Comment: But where do I get the dataFromFirstRequest, in subscribe method I get it via "response => " but in the mergeMap or pipe I don't know

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to flatten your observable returned by first http call and then switch to next http call depending on some logic ([`filter`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html) can help you with this). One of the operators that can help you is [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) which is considered as a safer default to `mergeMap` and maintain only one inner subscription (like it is in your case). I created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j52ksz) demo for you.